# Repurposing Jeditable jQuery plugin to use buttons instead of on-text click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, jeditable

I'm trying to slightly repurpose the functionality of the [Jeditable plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) to be controlled with buttons instead of clicking on the text. I've got a stripped-down version of the section I'm working on [here](http://dev.rjlacount.com/jeditable-test/).

Right now I'm triggering the text click event with my Edit button, hiding my Edit button once it's clicked, then making it reappear after the submit button is clicked. Here's my `jQuery` for the button click:

```
$('.jeditable-activate').click(function() {
    $(this).prev().click();
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
});
```

And here are the parameters I'm passing to the `Jeditible` function:

```
onedit : function() {
    $(this).siblings('.jeditable-activate').addClass('hidden');
},
onsubmit : function() {
    $(".jeditable-activate.hidden").removeClass('hidden');
}
```

I'd like to disable the default functionality of clicking on the text to edit, but I can't figure out a way to do this without breaking the functionality of my `Edit` button.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have found a way to do it since February but it might help someone else. I did the same using a custom jQuery event like that:

```
$('.edit').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', {
     id        : 'elementid',
     name      : 'newvalue',
[...]
     event     : 'whateverEvent'
});

$('.jeditable-activate').click(function() {
    $(this).prev().trigger('whateverEvent');
});
```